# Getting command not found on sudo

Tags: macos, terminal, command, sudo

Im trying: sudo /Users/oliver/Desktop/vpn/natvpn.sh

Getting command not found: sudo: /Users/oliver/Desktop/vpn/natvpn.sh: command not found

Can't seem to figure out how to fix it tried a lot of fixes on forums but no luck.

whereis sudo returns: /usr/bin/sudo

echo $PATH returns: /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /opt/X11/bin

I'm on mac os 11.2.3

What could be causing this and is there a fix?

Comment: Are you sure the script file exists at that exact path? Also, what is the script's shebang (first line)? Have you granted Terminal access to your Desktop (see [this q](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332673/what-and-how-does-macos-mojave-implement-to-restrict-applications-access-to-pers)?

Answer (score 0):

The sudo package is pre-installed on most Linux distributions. But seems your machine does not have it.
Did you installed sudo package on the machine, If not kindly try below command to install sudo

```
apt-get install sudo
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

```
sudo ~/Desktop/vpn/natvpn.sh
```

or

```
sudo /home/oliver/Desktop/vpn/natvpn.sh
```